cannot convert 'CHAR* {aka char*}' to 'wchar_t*' for argument '1' to 'wchar_t* wcscpy(wchar_t*, const wchar_t*)'
I am trying to do a Process Injection in C with the windws api (windows.h) and with tlhelp32.h. But I can not perform it. First of all I get the process and I make a comparison to know if the process I want to inject is executing but when I do the comparison I get an error saying that the types are wrong:
PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
Process32First(snapshot, &pe32);

do {
    if(wcscmp(pe32.szExeFile, L"mspaint.exe")==0) {
        HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pe32.th32ProcessID);
        LPVOID allocated_mem = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, sizeof(shellcode), (MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

        if (allocated_mem == NULL){
            printf("Memory allocation failed: %u\n", GetLastError());
            return 1;
        }

        printf("Memory page allocated at: 0x%p\n", allocated_mem);
        WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, allocated_mem, shellcode, sizeof(shellcode), NULL);

        HANDLE hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)allocated_mem, NULL, 0, NULL);

        if (hThread == NULL){
            printf("Failed to obtain handle to process: %u\n", GetLastError());
            return 1;
        }

        WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
        VirtualFreeEx(hThread, allocated_mem, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hThread);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        break;
    } 

} while(Process32Next(snapshot, &pe32));

I also tried without checking this and just puting the process ID but It dont work either. The shellcode (message box) is injected in the memory of the process but the message box is not displayed and I do not know why. I need help, ty.

There's no call to wcscpy() in this code. Please post the full error message (put it in a code block so the formatting is kept), including the line number.

Did you copy the error wrong and it's actually about wcscmp()? That means that pe32.szExeFile is a regular string, not a wide string. So get rid of the L prefix on the second argument.

You are using the TCHAR version of the TLHelp32 API, and are likely compiling your project for ANSI not UNICODE, thus PROCESSENTRY32 and Process32(First|Next) would be mapped to PROCESSENTRY32A and Process32(First|Next)A respectively.  As such, the pe32.szExeFile field would be a char string, and you are trying to pass that to wcscmp(), which expects a wchar_t string instead, hence the compiler error.
So, you need to either:

Leave your code as-is, but change your project config to enable UNICODE for the character set.

Use the TCHAR-based _tcscmp() or lstrcmp() instead of wcscmp():


#include <tchar.h>
...
if (_tcscmp(pe32.szExeFile, _T("mspaint.exe")) == 0) {

#include <windows.h>
...
if (lstrcmp(pe32.szExeFile, TEXT("mspaint.exe")) == 0) {


Use the ANSI strcmp() instead of wcscmp():

#include <string.h>
...
if (strcmp(pe32.szExeFile, "mspaint.exe") == 0) {


Stop using the TCHAR-based API altogether.  Use the wchar_t-based API instead:

PROCESSENTRY32W pe32;
pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
...
Process32FirstW(snapshot, &pe32);
do {
    if (wcscmp(pe32.szExeFile, L"mspaint.exe") == 0) {
    ...
}
while (Process32NextW(snapshot, &pe32));
...


Okey I made this change and now to comparison is working: if (lstrcmp(pe32.szExeFile, TEXT("mspaint.exe")) == 0). Now the shellcode is writed in memory but the handle that should execute it its not working, I did not change anything in the code but the comparison. Thanks.

"the handle that should execute [the shell code] its not working" - That is a separate issue that warrants its own question post.

@IvánSoler, for ways to inject, see the article. but the question is answered, and your new challenge deserves a new question.
